# Team cannot run iOS App on their phones

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I am currently working in a team of three. I have set up all the required certificates for push notifications and apple pay. I am able to run the application on my own iPhone6, but my team members cannot. 
They have to test the app on the simulator. I have checked the certificates multiple times and have added their phones UIIDs and created appropriate distribution profile.

Before we set up apple pay and push notifications we were able to use our phones to test without a problem.

Has anyone out there encountered this problem? And has found a solution?

As an alternative I have been using HockeyApp for adhoc distributions. It works great, but I would like my team to run and test the app on their phones whenever they need to.

Comment: Have you been able to make them install other distributed apps ? Do you have Apple developer or enterprise program ?

Comment: @Ronaldoh1 How are you installing app on devices? iTunes i guess??

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all certificate and profile from your mac and revoked your certificate from developer account and re-create all certificate and profile using developer account and use it.

Comment: Yeah i have done that already. I think the problem is that i dont have an enterprise account